# Equivalent of mRender with sorting based on underlying data in Jquery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

In jQuery Datatable plugin, I am using the mRender property for rendering data without altering the underlying data. http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#mRender

It is very usefull but I would like to sort column with underlying data and not based on formated string displayed into Table.

Do you know it it exists a property or a solution for doing that?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mRender` has been renamed to `columns.render`. You can check out the equivalent names in DataTables 1.10 for everything you may have used in 1.9 here: http://www.datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert

Examples of `columns.render` from the docs (http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render):

As a comma separated list:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajaxSource": "sources/deep.txt",
  "columns": [
    { "data": "engine" },
    { "data": "browser" },
    {
      "data": "platform",
      "render": "[, ].name"
    }
  ]
} );
```

As a function:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "data": "download_link",
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
      return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
    }
  } ]
} );
```

From @VivienPipo's addition below:

```
"render": function (data, type, full, meta) { 
    if (type == "display") { 
        return format_text_function(data); 
    } 
    return data; 
}
```